# Rails3 app displays garbled characters when using YAML file translated via Transifex

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, utf-8, yaml, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have translated a YAML file from English to German (with 'Austrian' accent), and have then downloaded the resulting YAML file. When I entered the german translations I used the Mac 'Option-u' keyboard shortcut to directly enter german umlauts such as ü, ä and ö.

When I subsequently downloaded the file from Transifex into my Rails3 app and attempted to use it, the characters are displayed garbled.

I tried to add

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

at the top of the file, but that didn't help, and I am having a hard time trying to figure out what encoding the YAML file is using to encode those multibyte characters.

Due to other UTF issues I have forced the YAML engine to syck in my app:

```
# to allow correct parsing of 'f\xC3\xBCr'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Patrick